# How to encrypt/decrypt data using Database Master Key (DMK)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I encrypt the data using DMK?

According to BOL, I don't have to open that key, but somehow have to pass 
something to: EncryptByKey function. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DMK is not for your own use. Is used to encrypt other keys (via `ALTER ... ADD ENCRYPTION BY MASTER KEY`), but never your data. This is a requirement, since the DMK can *change* and when such change happens all keys encrypted with DMK have to re-encrypted with the new DMK. The engine knows how to find the keys encrypted with the DMK, but it would be impossible to locate the *data* encrypted with DMK and a DMK rotation would leave such data 'perfectly encrypted' (ie. undecryptable, the key was lost).

Answer (score 0):

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320923/tools-to-encrypt-sql-server-database) out about encrypting database contents.

I would think that you would want to encrypt/decrypt data in your application though...